# How to efficiently store 1 million words and query them by starts_with, contains, or ends_with?

Tags: database, algorithm, memory, full-text-search

How do sites like [this](https://www.morewords.com/contains/c) store tens of thousands of words "containing c", or like [this](https://word.tips/words-with/d/and/c/), "words with d and c", or [even further](https://word.tips/unscramble/caudk/), "unscrambling" the word like `CAUDK` and finding that the database has `duck`. Curious from an algorithms/efficiency perspective how they would accomplish this:

Would a database be used, or would the words simply be stored in memory and quickly traversed? If a database was used (and each word was a record), how would you make these sorts of queries (with PostgreSQL for example, `contains`, `starts_with`, `ends_with`, and `unscrambles`)?

I guess the easiest thing to do would be to store all words in memory (sorted?), and just traverse the whole million or less word list to find the matches? But how about the unscramble one?

Basically wondering the efficient way this would be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Containing `C`" amounts to `count(C) > 0`. Unscrambling `CAUDC` amounts to `count(C) <= 2 && count(A) <= 1 && count(U) <= 1 && count(D) <= 1`. So both queries could be efficiently answered by a database with 26 indices, one for the count of each letter in the alphabet.

Here is a quick and dirty python `sqlite3` demo:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cur = conn.cursor()

alphabet = [chr(ord('A')+i) for i in range(26)]
alphabet_set = set(alphabet)
columns = ['word TEXT'] + [f'{c}_count TINYINT DEFAULT 0' for c in alphabet]
create_cmd = f'CREATE TABLE abc ({", ".join(columns)})'
cur.execute(create_cmd)

for c in alphabet:
    cur.execute(f'CREATE INDEX {c}_index ON abc ({c}_count)')

def insert(word):
    counts = Counter(word)
    columns = ['word'] + [f'{c}_count' for c in counts.keys()]
    counts = [f'"{word}"'] + [f'{n}' for n in counts.values()]
    var_str = f'({", ".join(columns)})'
    val_str = f'({", ".join(counts)})'
    insert_cmd = f'INSERT INTO abc {var_str} VALUES {val_str}'
    cur.execute(insert_cmd)

def unscramble(text):
    counts = {a:0 for a in alphabet}
    for c in text:
        counts[c] += 1

    where_clauses = [f'{c}_count <= {n}' for (c, n) in counts.items()]
    select_cmd = f'SELECT word FROM abc WHERE {" AND ".join(where_clauses)}'
    cur.execute(select_cmd)
    return list(sorted([tup[0] for tup in cur.fetchall()]))


print('Building sqlite table...')
with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as f:
    word_set = set(line.strip().upper() for line in f)
    for word in word_set: 
        if all(c in alphabet_set for c in word):
            insert(word)
print('Table built!')

d = defaultdict(list)
for word in unscramble('CAUDK'):
    d[len(word)].append(word)

print("unscramble('CAUDK'):")
for n in sorted(d):
    print(' '.join(d[n]))
```

Output:

```
Building sqlite table...
Table built!
unscramble('CAUDK'):
A C D K U
AC AD AK AU CA CD CU DA DC KC UK
AUK CAD CUD
DUCK
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how this indexing and count structure would work, I can't quite follow how to implement it.

Comment: @Lance I added a demo.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I am curious how much space 26 indexes will take, need to figure out how to calculate that :) Also, how does this compare to @caveman's solution below as well, in terms of speed/scalability?

Comment: Ideally everything would be stored in the database, but not sure if it would exponentially explode the size of the database, with millions of words (across various languages), with tons of indexes.

Comment: Finally, what about how to handle prefix/suffix (starts with/ends with) in this sort of system?

Comment: These indices are quite flat (the number of distinct values that occur as `*_count` values is much smaller than the total number of rows). So each index takes up O(N) bytes, where N is the number of words in the database. I believe the constant factor in that O(N) should be the number of bytes in the `PRIMARY KEY` datatype, which you should be able to set to `INT` (4 bytes).

Comment: This should outperform @caveman's solution in terms of speed/scalability. Finally, for prefix queries, I would simply maintain an in-memory [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). A second trie housing the reversed words can be used for suffix queries.

Comment: What if I wanted to handle the Chinese language (search for words containing some random characters), there are 80k+ unique characters in Chinese (as opposed to 26 alphabet characters in English), how would I do it then? [Related](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/313922/how-to-store-and-query-strings-matching-prefix-or-suffix-in-postgresql).

Comment: I posted an answer in your question. Essentially, for languages like Chinese, to support unscramble queries, I recommend an in-memory hash-map mapping each character to the list of words (or word indices) containing that character.

Comment: Thank you! That helps to see how it should ideally/typically be done. Last piece, what if instead of an in-memory trie, we had an [ngram approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72809209/how-to-find-all-words-containing-ngram-x-and-ngram-y-in-postgresql-using-manual), is that good? Thanks for all the help BTW, sorry for so many questions, just really curious how to implement this for some reason :)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by an n-gram approach, but if your intention is to use something other than a trie to support prefix queries, then I don't suggest it. The trie data structure exists precisely to answer prefix queries. If you're trying to reduce memory footprint, then trie-like mechanics can conceivably be achieved via database, but I don't advise this unless you find clear evidence that it's worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure what they're doing, but I suggest this algorithm for `contains` and `unscramble` (and, I think, can be trivially extended to `starts with` or `end with`):

1. User submits a set of letters in the form of a string.  Say, user submits `bdsfa`.
2. The algorithm sorts that string in (1).  So, query becomes `abdfs`
3. Then, to find all words with those letters in them, the algorithm simply accesses the directory `database/a/b/d/f/s/` and finds all words with those letters in.  In case it finds the directory to be empty, it goes one level up: `database/a/b/d/f/` and shows result there.

So, now, the question is, how to index the database of millions of words as done in step (3)?  `database/` directory will have 26 directories inside it for `a` to `z`, each of which will have 26-1 directories for all letters, except their parent's.  E.g.:

```
database/a/{b,c,...,z}`
database/b/{a,c,...,z}`
...
database/z/{a,c,...,y}`
```

This tree structure will be only 26 level deep.  Each branch will have no more than 26 elements.  So browsing this directory structure is scalable.

Words will be stored in the leaves of this tree.  So, the word `apple` will be stored in `database/a/e/l/p/leaf_apple`.  In that place, you will also find other words such as `leap`.  More specifically:

```
database/
  a/
    e/
      l/
        p/
          leaf_apple
          leaf_leap
          leaf_peal
          ...
```

This way, you can efficiently reach the subset of target words as `O(log n)`, where `n` is total number of words in your database.

You can further optimise this by adding additional indices.  For example, there are too many words containing `a`, and the website won't display them all (at least not in the 1st page).  Instead, the website may say `there are total 500,000 many words containing 'a', here is 100 examples`.  In order to obtain `500,000` efficiently, the number of children at every level can be added during the indexing.  E.g.  `database/{a,b,...,z}/{num_children,

```
`database/
  {...}/
    {num_children,...}/
      {num_childred,...}/
        ...
```

Here, `num_children` is just a leaf node, just like `leaf_WORD`.  All leafs are files.

Depending on the load that this website has, it may not require to load this database in memory.  It may simply leave it to the operating system to decide which portion of its file system to cache in memory as a read-time optimisation.

Personally, I think, as a criticism to applications, I think developers tend to jump into requiring RAM too fast even when a simple file system trick can do the job without any noticeable difference to the end user.

Comment: What if the alphabet was all 1 million unicode characters instead of 26 alphabet characters, then what? :) Like searching all languages.

Comment: @Lance - In that case, I suggest to add a language detection layer as a 1st stage.  Then, once the language is identified, I guess most languages have sensibly small enough alphabet space.  Odd unicode symbols can be ignored, or replaced by a more common character (a pre-processing step).   That said, I don't think that the site that you've shown us actually supports such large pool of languages (I tried Arabic and it failed).

Comment: Thanks, I have to let your answer sink in, the exact organization of the files I'm still not quite following yet. Also, what about in-memory [tries](https://dev.to/seanpgallivan/solution-prefix-and-suffix-search-11m5#javascript-code), would that be some solution as well? I'm not sure, still learning.

Comment: @Lance - Is that containing a loop, in memory- that is iterating over every single word for every query?

Comment: Yeah I guess so, dang, yeah that must be slow. Actually, hmm, I still don't know for sure.

Comment: @Lance - Checkout the answer from @dsh; he is basically saying what I say, except generally, without digging deep into how the indexing is done.  Both of the methods are doable on disk, or on RAM.  My answer is simply proposing a specific data indexing method.  But there are other data indexing methods than tree structures.

Comment: Alright starting to click some more! How would it be extended to handle starts/ends with? And what if the search word has duplicate letters, like `brittl` or something.

Comment: `database_starts/{a,b,...,z}/{leaf_1,leaf_2, ...}` where leaves are only those that start with the letter in their parent directory.  Same can be done with ends.  If you want with both, i.e. words that start by X and end by Y, then `database_starts+ends/X/Y/{leaf_1,leaf_2, ...}`.  If the collection of words are too big (i.e. `{leaf_1, leaf_2, ...}` is too many, you may sub-divide it into a tree recursively in a way to reflect the amount you want to show to the users in a single page.

Comment: About duplicate letters, if you care about them being treated differently, then you could store the word `apple` in `database/a/e/l/p/p/leaf_apple`.  Note that there is `/p/p/` twice to account that this is a word with `p` repeated twice in it.  But, if you don't care about making duplication special, then you may throw it under `a/e/l/p/...` along the rest, regardless of how many duplicates they have.  Both options are possible.