# How to find all words containing ngram x and ngram y in PostgreSQL (using manual implementation of ngrams)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Say we have two tables in PostgreSQL:

- `words` with `text` field containing the word (English word for now), and `id`.
- `ngrams` containing `text` field and mapping to `word_id`.

How would you "select all words which contain x and y"?

```
select * from words
inner join ngrams on ngrams.word_id = words.id
where ngrams.text = x
and ngrams.text = y
```

The general problem is, how do I do an `AND` but use two different records from the `ngrams` table? What I did just there is compare the *same ngram text value* to two different variables, asking for AND. That doesn't make sense, it should somehow use two different ngram records. How generally do you do that in PostgreSQL?

*Note, I don't want to use PostgreSQL full-text search functionality. I am trying to understand how to implement it at a lower level (manually), and also want to apply to hundreds of languages beyond just English (like to Chinese, which has at least 80k characters).*

https://medium.com/@evanwhalen/anatomy-of-an-n-gram-search-b30c6f20ad39

Answer (score 1):

You can use two `exists` subqueries:

```
select w.* from words where exists (select 1 from ngrams n 
    where n.word_id = w.id and n.text = x) -- check if the word has associated ngram of x
  and exists (select 1 from ngrams n 
    where n.word_id = w.id and n.text = y) -- also ensure that the word has associated ngram of y
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-phrased question.

What you're looking for is a [Self Join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Self-join).
So we query `ngrams` once, calling it e.g. `a`,
and query it a 2nd time, calling it `b`.
Then the WHERE clause looks for `a.text = x AND b.text = y`.
(I prolly would have named the column `ngram` instead, whatever.)

Let's look for just the ngrams, no word.

```sql
select *
from ngrams a
join ngrams b
where a.text = x
      and b.text = y
      and a.text <= b.text;
```

Additionally, we only want the lower triangle
of this Cartesian cross product,
so constrain `a.text <= b.text`.
No need to retrieve both ("th", "he") and ("he", "th")
for "the".
Set up your query beforehand so that `x <= y` obtains.

With the ngrams in hand, it's straightforward
to additionally JOIN against `words`
and maybe use GROUP BY to boil them down to *distinct* words.

Tacking on an ORDER BY,
at least during debugging,
will make the result set a bit easier to read.